How to rebase and squash commits on a (already-pushed) branch, and then push it to the remote, when force pushing is disabled?
I often find myself working on a feature branch, with lots of chore: and wip: commits, that need to be continuously pushed to the remote to prevent losing work in case of client problems.
After finishing implementing the feature, I want to get rid of all these intermediary commits, by rebasing and squashing locally.
Now, how can I push the rebased branch to the remote, when it has force pushing disabled?
Do I need to create a completely new branch and push it instead? After all, the remote-tracking branch won't allow pushing the rebased branch directly.
I found myself in a similar situation recently, where I had an unsigned commit, that was then signed by rebasing and editing.

Don't use the remote as a backup system. If you are concerned about losing data from your local repository, back up your local repository.

@chepner How would you back up your local repository? Most people I know commit and push their work at the end of the day, no matter whether it's done or not

The  same way you back up anything else on your local disk.

If all force-pushing on this remote is disabled, then you can simply push to a different remote — a private, personal one that you control completely — just for the sake of preventing loss of work in progress, and don't push to the remote that has force pushing disabled until you've rejiggered the history of this branch the way you want it.

Thank you. What’s the advantage of pushing to a different remove over pushing to a different branch in the same remote l, as suggested by @jthill?

None, if you are permitted to force push to some branches on the same remote. But if you are never permitted to force push to any branches on the same remote, you will probably need another remote. Just to give a rudimentary example, I often rebase my work in progress onto a fresh copy of origin/main, and you can't push that without force-pushing. It's either that or keep deleting and re-creating the remote branch, as you say. In other words, jthill's approach is viable, but I'm suggesting to you the alternative which I in fact use in this situations.


that need to be continuously pushed to the remote to prevent losing work in case of client problems.

Push your belt-and-suspenders backups of WIP history to a WIP branch that you can force or delete, only push to the protected-from-rewrites real branch when you've constructed the exact history you want to publish there.
git checkout -b WIP/branch origin/branch    # start a new WIP branch off origin
git push -u origin WIP/branch               # push to that by default
work 
commit
push
rebase
squash
la la
git push origin @:branch                    # publish the current tip as `branch`
git push --delete origin WIP/branch         # delete the WIP history (if you want)

if the upstream won't let you force-push anything, well, the WIP branch is yours, you can just delete and recreate it at will. The WIP/ prefix is arbitrary.

If force pushing is disabled, you won't be able to rewrite the commit history on the remote repository by default. However, there are still ways to rebase and squash commits on your branch while respecting the rules set by the repository.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
